# How to access property of a property of a JSON object if the initial property is a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and have successfully made a system where it stores user's variables in a JSON file in this format:

```json
{
  "801479782613123123": {
    "status": true
  },
  "725581416720629863": {
    "status": true
  }
}
```

My current problem is that I am unable to check this 'status' property is true or false when I pass in a variable as the initial property. Here is my code:

```js
let statusPath = './commands/afkstatus.json';
    let statusRead = fs.readFileSync(statusPath);
    let statusFile = JSON.parse(statusRead); //Ready for use
    let userID = message.author.id
    if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
        let ping = message.mentions.users.first();
        let status = statusFile[userID.status];
        if (statusFile[userID.status]) {
            message.channel.send(`Message`);
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, there is no error message, the message simply does not get sent.

Comment: Is `message.author.id` of type string or number? If it is of type number, it will not work because `801479782613123123` is bigger than [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). When you use that number as a key, it will convert it to a string and `String(801479782613123123)` is `"801479782613123100"` <-- notice the last to digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `let status = statusFile[userID].status` instead.